# UIWindow subviews not working on iOS 8

Tags: uiview, ios8

I've been working for 2 days on it and can not solve. I have a fullscreen button that i show in my UIViewController like this;

```
_tutorialButton.frame = CGRectMake(0.0f, 0.0f, [UIScreen mainScreen].bounds.size.width, [UIScreen mainScreen].bounds.size.height);
 UIWindow *window = [[UIApplication sharedApplication].windows objectAtIndex:0];
 [[[window subviews] objectAtIndex:0] addSubview:_tutorialButton];
```

This code works exactly what i expect on iOS 7 and earlier OS. However it doesn't work on iOS 8. I don't want to use

```
_tutorialButton.layer.zPosition = MAXFLOAT;
```

because it's dirty solution for me. Also iif i use this method, i need to hide my UITabBar and UINavigationBar. Is this iOS 8 bug or am i doing something wrong?

Comment: Have you tried the new "Debug view hierarchy" feature in Xcode 6?

Comment: Yes i've tried and can not see my button in hierarchy.

Answer (score 1):

In iOS 8 i've found the same problem.
It turned out that on some screens UIWindow has several subviews instead of one and only.
Adding my view to the last UIWindow subview solved this, though I'm not sure whether I should rework my entire navigation instead.

Anyway, try modifying your code like this:

```
 [[[window subviews] objectAtIndex:[[window subviews] count]-1] addSubview:_tutorialButton];
```

**upd:**
My final solution was to add the subview not to UIWindows' subviews, but to my navigation controller's view instead. Thus you wan't have to guess which UIWindow subview is your's in case there are several of 'em